# filter markers in logback

Tags: scala, logging, logback

I have project on scala.
I use this lib for logging
https://github.com/typesafehub/scala-logging

i create logger

```
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger
val log                 = Logger(getClass)
```

and two markers

```
    import org.slf4j.{Marker, MarkerFactory}
    private val marker: Marker = MarkerFactory.getMarker("DP")
    private val marker2: Marker = MarkerFactory.getMarker("ST")
```

I use log in my controller

```
log.debug(marker, "----"
log.debug(marker2, "++++")
```

This is my logback

```
<appender name="STDOUTTime" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%coloredLevel %logger{30} - %marker - %d{yyyy/MM/dd/HH:mm:ss.SSS/Z} - %message%n%xException{3}</pattern>
    </encoder>

    <turboFilter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.MarkerFilter">
        <Marker>DP</Marker>
        <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
        <OnMismatch>DENY</OnMismatch>
    </turboFilter>

    <turboFilter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.MarkerFilter">
        <Marker>ST</Marker>
        <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
        <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </turboFilter>
</appender>

<logger name="ds.forwarding" level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUTTime"/>
</logger>

<root level="ERROR">

</root>
```

now when i run my controller i have output in console:

```
[debug] d.f.c.a.s.InputStatisticController - DP - 2017/09/25/11:55:58.603/+0300 - ----
[debug] d.f.c.a.s.InputStatisticController - ST - 2017/09/25/11:55:58.603/+0300 - ++++
```

Now I have a questions:

- Why marker and marker2 is visible, why DENY does not work?
- How can I exclude two markers?
- How can I exclude only one marker?

Comment: It can be because, the class name or the package name where you created the logger and logging is `test`. So its taking precedence over the root logger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `logback.xml` which denies both `DP` and `ST` markers.

```
<configuration>
    <turboFilter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.MarkerFilter">
        <Marker>DP</Marker>
        <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
    </turboFilter>

    <turboFilter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.MarkerFilter">
        <Marker>ST</Marker>
        <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
    </turboFilter>

    <appender name="STDOUTTime" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%coloredLevel %logger{30} - %marker - %d{yyyy/MM/dd/HH:mm:ss.SSS/Z} - %message%n%xException{3}</pattern>
        </encoder>

    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUTTime"/>
    </root>  
</configuration>
```

The mistakes about your file:

1. Your file doesn't start with `<configuration>` and end with `</configuration>`
2. Filters are not in the correct namespace. They should be under `<configuration>` (same level with appenders).
3. No need to use `<onMisMatch>` flags in your case. It may cause to mix the things up.
4. Since your logger is named as `ds.forwarding`, in the class you have to be sure that you are calling that logger. In your case, you call the logger with `getClass` method. In my `logback.xml` file, I added the `appender` to my `root` logger. Therefore, it is sufficient to call it via `Logger(getClass)` method.
5. Always be careful about levels. I set the level to `DEBUG`.

Once you set the configuration properly, simply change the `<onMatch>` property to `ALLOW` if you want the logger to print it, or `DENY` if you don't. Simply setting both to `ALLOW` will result in printing all the markers, on the other hand, if you set both of them to `DENY`, that markers won't be printed.